# javascript cookie arithmetic count

Tags: javascript, cookies, integer

I am trying to use cookies to store numbers and when I am trying to do count it's not working.

```
        var count2 = "2";
        var count2 = parseInt(count2);
        document.cookie=counter1= + count2 + 21;
        window.alert(parseInt(readCookie('counter1')));
        window.alert(count2 + 1);
```

First results: 221
Second results: 3

The problem is when I am getting the count from cookie.

That's the read function.

```
function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
```

I'd like to store numbers in cookies and then convert to integers.

Comment: What is the variable `counter1`?

Comment: @Aim Is your code copied directly? Surely the cookie name should be a string: `document.cookie="counter1=" + count2 + 21;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to add `count2` with `21`, you'll need to wrap them in brackets, as you're concatenating a string so your numbers will be parsed as strings, hence `2 + 21 = "221"`, instead of `= 23`.

Try `document.cookie="counter1=" + (count2 + 21);`